# How to stop Google Play Billing from charging until an api request confirms the purchase can be made

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I have a question about the Google Play Billing Library (version 5) but I guess older versions are fine too.

In Google Play Billing, the purchase flow is launched like below:

```
BillingResult billingResult = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(getActivity(), billlingFlowParams);
```

A listener waits for the purchase response, like below:

```
PurchasesUpdatedListener purchasesUpdatedListener = new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(@NonNull @NotNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable List<com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase> list) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && list != null) {
                    ....
                    ....
                    Additional code here that makes an api request based on the Purchase Object
                    }
        };
```

The problem is that as soon as we confirm the purchase Google charges for the purchase but I have a backend that also process the purchase, ie confirm the purchase is applicable etc... As a result what can happen is that someone confirms the purchase, Google charges the person but my backend goes, the purchase cannot be done for whatever reason. So technically the purchase shouldn't have gone through but google charges it no matter what since it does that as soon as we confirm a purchase.

I should mention that the API requires data from the `Purchase` object, which contains the `purchaseToken` and the `subscriptionId`**strong text** from the `onPurchasesUpdated` method.

My question is how are people overcoming this? As long as`BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK` is the response code the purchase goes through regardless of what the backend thinks. I don't believe I have control over the `BillingResult.getResponseCode()`.

Comment: You could skip acknowledging the purchase, which I believe will result in an automatic cancellation in something like 2 days. But users might complain about that? Probably better just to redo how you determine if it's valid from your server so you can do that before initiating the purchase

Comment: Thanks, I just saw that earlier too. My guess is that the refund can take up to 3 days from google?